# float row figure box - two lines in caption

Tags: floats, line-breaking, captions, floatrow

I am trying to get the caption on two lines with this command but using `\\` does not work.  If anyone know how to do this it would be helpful

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
 \caption{Incentive Tune: $\theta_{1} = 0.0167$, $\theta_{2} = 0.008$ }
\includegraphics[scale= .35]{chapters/Chapter09/ch9_3.eps}%
}{%
}
\ffigbox{%
\caption{Incentive Tune: $\theta_{1} = 0.019$, $\theta_{2} = 0.01$ }
\includegraphics[scale=.35]{chapters/Chapter09/ch9_4.eps}%
}{%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, make your code into a minimal example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, showing the necessary packages for getting the output (we can deal with EPS files quite easily, so they're not important).

Answer (score 1):

Load the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox
  {\includegraphics[scale= .35]{example-image-a}}
  {\caption{Incentive Tune: \\ $\theta_{1} = 0.0167$, \\ $\theta_{2} = 0.008$}%
  }
\ffigbox
  {\includegraphics[scale=.35]{example-image-b}}
  {\caption{Incentive Tune: \\ $\theta_{1} = 0.019$, \\ $\theta_{2} = 0.01$}%
  }
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]